# Changing Pitch and Speed in android by NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, pcm

I have  decoded PCM by NDK (mpg123),i want to change pitch and speed dynamically... but how would i suppose to work on speed and pitch separately .. all i can do is change the sample rate in audio-track .. and i have also implemented Sonic-NDK ,in whitch there is a .bin file in raw folder which is playing perfactly, now i am playing .wav to sonic- NDK,then there is but the thing Sonic need to feed PCM so i am converting to pcm by mpg123 and feeding it dynamically .. but the whole process is not fast enough and i am hearing a gap in loop.. code is :

```java
void recursive() {
        buffer = new short[minBufferSize];
        err = NativeWrapper.decodeMP3(minBufferSize * 2, buffer);
        byte[] bufferbyte = ShortToByte_Twiddle_Method(buffer);
        sonic.putBytes(bufferbyte, bufferbyte.length);
        int available = sonic.availableBytes();
        modifiedSamples = new byte[available ];
        sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
        track.write(modifiedSamples, 0, available); // Write
        if (err != MPG123_DONE) {
            recursive();
        }
    }
```

so now i have two queries:

1. how could i remove gap and noise in chunks (code below)
2. is there any other way to achieve operation on pitch and speed dynamically is there any other library or something or what else i should do.

Comment: Why are you allocating new arrays for every buffer that you decode? That seems wasteful.